# OpenFileDialog in vba that returns the directory as a string

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have been looking everywhere and I am very surprised that this is not already easily available as a function in VBA.

I need a function that when called, opens a filedialog where people can select 1 file (not more, just 1) and then the function returns the location of the file (including filename+extension) as a string.

At first i thought: " How hard can that be, I'ts really simple in VB.NET.."

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean like htis?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ofD As Object
    Dim Fil

    Set ofD = Application.FileDialog(3)

    ofD.AllowMultiSelect = False
    ofD.Show

    For Each Fil In ofD.SelectedItems
        MsgBox Fil
    Next
End Sub
```

The above `For` loop is useful if `AllowMultiSelect` is `True`

Here is another example if there is only one file.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ofD As Object
    Dim Fil

    Set ofD = Application.FileDialog(3)

    ofD.AllowMultiSelect = False

    If ofD.Show = False Then
        MsgBox "User Pressed Cancel"
    Else
        MsgBox ofD.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you please explain to me what the "3" and "1"  stand for ?

Comment: Sorry was out for a client meet. I believe this link will answer all your queries? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195878%28v=office.11%29.aspx?

Comment: how would you do this in order to select a folder?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem earlier this week here the solution I used.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/294728-browse-folder-visual-basic-applications.html

Hope it help you too.

Comment: This seems like it could work, except for the fact that I get an error  that "Filedialog" in "Dim fldr As fileDialog" is not an existing type..

Comment: That solution uses early binding so requires you to set a reference for *Microsoft Office [version] Object Library*.