# Import Specification Access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an import specification in Access for a CSV file.

I want the user to:

- Use the import specification
- specify the file to import

Is there a way in VBA to somehow show the saved imports window where the user can specify a path or change this path dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can [show a File dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971619/openfiledialog-in-vba-that-returns-the-directory-as-a-string) and then call the [`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx) method with the user-selected file and your import specification.